# How can I do this int to String transformation?

Tags: java

I want to transform an `int` to a `String` such that:

> 0 -> "a"
>   1 -> "b"
>   2 -> "c"
>   and so on...

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean 'String a'? Like in an array or just String a,b,c,d?

Comment: As in if input = 0, output = "a"

Comment: You could create an array, `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ...}` and then if you want to convert `0` to `a`, just do `String letter = array[number]`

Comment: Leman That just makes no sense in my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert from the character literal:

```
int input = 0;
String output = new Character((char) (input + 'a')).toString();
```

Comment: or `String output = String.valueOf((char)(input+'a'))`

Comment: +1, though I'd use the character literal `'a'` instead of `97` since it gets promoted to int anyway and is clearer where the value comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but it sounds like you want to be able to convert integers 0-25 to their corresponding alphabetical characters.  If that's the case, your best bet logically is probably to use an [enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).  Though I may not be fully seeing the purpose of what you're trying to do (which is likely).

You could also write a utility method which just has a big [switch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method, for some java library flavor:

```
int value;
String output = Integer.toString(value + 10, 36);
```

which uses a radix of 36 to locate the right letter.